# How to avoid 0xFF prefix when converting char to short?

Tags: c++, hex, storage

When I do:

```
cout << std::hex << (short)('\x3A') << std::endl;
cout << std::hex << (short)('\x8C') << std::endl;
```

I expect the following output:

```
3a
8c
```

but instead, I have:

```
3a
ff8c
```

I suppose that this is due to the way `char`—and more precisely a *signed* `char`—is stored in memory: everything below 0x80 would not be prefixed; the value 0x80 and above, on the other hand, would be prefixed with 0xFF.

When given a `signed char`, how do I get a hexadecimal representation of the actual character inside it? In other words, how do I get 0x3A for `\x3A`, and 0x8C for `\x8C`?

I don't think a conditional logic is well suited here. While I can subtract 0xFF00 from the resulting `short` when needed, it doesn't seem very clear.

Comment: why are you using char in the first place? why not 0x3a etc.? the ff is from sign extension because your compiler happens to consider char signed. the result is a (signed) short, but hex output mode treats all integers as unsigned, so you see the ff but no negative sign.

Comment: @CruzJean: the context is that the `char` comes from a `char *` containing binary data. First two bytes correspond to an identifier. In order to recompose the identifier, I was doing `unsigned short id = (unsigned short)d[0] * 256 + d[1]`, which, in some cases, was not giving the results I was expecting originally.

Comment: was the data written as shorts?

Comment: @CruzJean: since the ID is two bytes long, I would say yes, `unsigned short`.

Comment: If it was written as shorts you should read it as a short. Composing two bytes manually assumes a specific endianness and would be slower than reading directly as a short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output might make more sense if you looked at it in decimal instead of hexadecimal:

```
std::cout << std::dec << (short)('\x3A') << std::endl;
std::cout << std::dec << (short)('\x8C') << std::endl;
```

output:

```
58
-116
```

The values were cast to `short`, so we are (most commonly) dealing with 16 bit values. The 16-bit binary representation of -116 is `1111 1111 1000 1100`, which becomes `FF8C` in hexadecimal. So the output is correct given what you requested (on systems where `char` is a signed type). *So not so much the way the `char` is stored in memory, but more the way the bits are interpreted. As an unsigned value, the 8-bit pattern `1000 1100` represents -116, and the conversion to `short` is supposed to preserve this value, rather than preserving the bits.*

Your desired output  of a hexadecimal `8C` corresponds (for a `short`) to the decimal value `140`. To get this value out of 8 bits, the value has to be interpreted as an unsigned 8-bit value (since the largest signed 8-bit value is 127). So the data needs to be interpreted as an `unsigned char` before it gets expanded to some flavor of `short`. For a character literal like in the example code, this would look like the following.

```
std::cout << std::hex << (unsigned short)(unsigned char)('\x3A') << std::endl;
std::cout << std::hex << (unsigned short)(unsigned char)('\x8C') << std::endl;
```

Most likely, the real code would have variables instead of character literals. If that is the case, then rather than casting to an `unsigned char`, it might be more convenient to declare the variable to be of `unsigned char` type. **Which is possibly the type you should be using anyway,** based on the fact that you want to see its hexadecimal value. Not definitively, but this does suggest that the value is seen simply as a byte of data rather than as a number, and that suggests that an unsigned type is appropriate. Have you looked at [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte)?

One other nifty thought to throw out: the following also gives the desired output as a reasonable facsimile of using an `unsigned char` variable.

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned char operator "" _u (char c) { return c; } // Suffix for unsigned char literals

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::hex << (unsigned short)('\x3A'_u) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << (unsigned short)('\x8C'_u) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more straightforward approach is to cast a `signed char` to an `unsigned char`. In other words, this:

```
cout << std::hex << (short)(unsigned char)('\x3A') << std::endl;
cout << std::hex << (short)(unsigned char)('\x8C') << std::endl;
```

produces the expected result:

```
3a
8c
```

Not sure this is particularly clear, though.